# MySQL issue : adding the result of a query to a column in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  from_unixtime(lastSaleTime/1000, '%Y-%d-%m %h:%i:%s.'),
  CAST(EXTRACT(MICROSECOND FROM from_unixtime(lastSaleTime/1000))/1000 
  AS SIGNED)
) FROM IEX_Tick;
```

This code returns a column of values, and I want to add all that data to a new column that I created. This was suggested last time:

```
UPDATE IEX_Tick SET SomeColumn = (
   SELECT CONCAT(
       from_unixtime(lastSaleTime/1000, '%Y-%d-%m %h:%i:%s.'),
       CAST(EXTRACT(MICROSECOND FROM from_unixtime(lastSaleTime/1000))/1000 AS SIGNED)
   ) FROM IEX_Tick;
)
```

However I get the error "You can't specify target table 'IEX_Tick' for update in FROM clause. I looked that up and we have tried some of the workarounds, for example:

```
UPDATE IEX_Tick SET SomeColumn = (
   SELECT CONCAT(
       from_unixtime(lastSaleTime/1000, '%Y-%d-%m %h:%i:%s.'),
       CAST(EXTRACT(MICROSECOND FROM from_unixtime(lastSaleTime/1000))/1000 AS SIGNED)
   ) FROM (Select * from IEX_Tick) as RRR;
)
```

But it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply eschew the subquery:

```
UPDATE IEX_Tick
    SET SomeColumn = CONCAT(from_unixtime(lastSaleTime/1000, '%Y-%d-%m %h:%i:%s.'),
                             CAST(EXTRACT(MICROSECOND FROM from_unixtime(lastSaleTime/1000))/1000 AS SIGNED)
                            );
```